# Mountain Lion upgrade and many sites are not opening

Tags: macos

I've upgraded to Mountain Lion and since then many sites including Google (and all of its related services), facebook and many other sites are not opening. i can't even open gmail.com. the name resolutions seem to be working fine.

> dig gmail.com
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> gmail.com ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
>   answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24840 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;gmail.com.          IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: gmail.com.     300 IN  A   209.85.175.17
>   gmail.com.        300 IN  A   209.85.175.19 gmail.com.        300 IN  A   209.85.175.83
>   gmail.com.        300 IN  A   209.85.175.18
>
> ;; Query time: 262 msec ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) ;; WHEN: Sat
>   Jul 28 11:44:03 2012 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91

In the status bar, it says **Waiting for *domain***. and later it shows errors like EMPTY RESPONSE, TIMED OUT etc.

i even can't open yahoo, twitter. i've tested this from Chrome, Safari, Firefox. But all these sites open from my wife's macbook (snow leopard) that is using same internet connection.

however, i can open many sites including all SE sites, github and many others.

is there anything i can do? as i can't google, i'm literally can't search web too :(.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i've just entered into the Recovery mode and i see i can access those pages. But the problem persists in the normal macosx startup!

Comment: how are you connected to the internet?

Comment: WiMAX. but when i connect via WiFi it same result.

Comment: I have same problem. I'm using Timecapsule and connected via WLAN.

Comment: Of course, telling us about your wife's MacBook doesn't make us believe you cannot Google ;-) (Can you please use upper case i's?)

Comment: Any chance all troublesome sites use HTTPS? (Stack Exchange's authentication does so too, but that might have some fallback?)

Comment: your first comment confuses me whether this is related or not! capital i does not solve my problem ;). yes, i googled a while from her laptop but did not find any solution! btw, no many HTTPS sites are opening fine!

Comment: Hmm, so it's not DNS? Have you narrowed it down to http or does it happen on every port/protocol? Does pinging google work? What about `curl -v gmail.com`?

Comment: ping to google.com, gmail.com works fine. curl to gmail redirects to a number of urls and each of them are coming fine without any problem! btw, i can access those pages from other internet connection. again, i can use those pages from other laptop using this current connection! very peculiar! :s btw, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

This issue affected several people after upgrading to Mountain Lion. For many, reducing their MTU size solved the issue:

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Select **Network**.
3. Select your connection and choose **Advanced...**
4. Select **Hardware**.
5. Change **Configuration** to **Manually**
6. Reduce the MTU size to 1300. Most people had good experiences with this value.
7. Observe how `ping` behaves over time. You can further reduce the MTU size in steps of 4.

However, there seems to be another issue: Proxies. The solution suggested here is:

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Select **Network**.
3. Select your connection and choose **Advanced...**
4. Select **Proxies**.
5. Turn off **Auto Discovery Proxies**.
6. **Apply** the settings.

This should be fixed with an upgrade to OS X 10.8.1 (not sure if an upgrade to Mountain Lion directly brings you to the latest upgrade, or to 10.8.0).

Actually, I would first try the upgrade to 10.8.1. If this does not work, try the proxy solution. If this does not work, try the MTU size reduction.

Comment: Thanks for your help! but all of a sudden this issue is resolved few days ago! probably after several updates that came through App Store.

Comment: Sounds like the update to 10.8.1 was part of your updates.

Comment: yes, though current version is 10.8.2  :). thanks